# Eclipse: where Eclipse installation files are located?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, sdk, adb, adt

I downloaded and setup eclipse under Ubuntu .. now I am trying to connect to my Nexus-7, it looks like I don't have adb installed or its path is not set:

```
No command 'adb' found
```

.. so trying to locate the android-sdk but can't find it.

my questions are:

1. where exactly does the Eclipse installation files are located ?
2. if ADT includes adb and fastboot, then where are they and how to set
   their paths ?
3. if not, how to install them on Ubuntu  ?

thanks

Comment: Did you install the Android Eclipse?

Comment: @Gander7: I have no idea .. I just typed `sudo apt-get install eclipse` .. then after installation and from within the eclipse I added the _ADT Plugin_ following this [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) .. followed by installing the subclipse using the same feature of _Install New Software_ .. how to check if I have the android eclipse ?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions here: 
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html
Below you can find the associated pages

Here is where you can download the entire bundle: 
Click on Download for other platforms.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Follow instructions on this page if you already have an IDE working.
For Linux click on the link at the bottom "Information for other platforms"
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

All information for installing, configuring and starting to use Android Eclipse should be on the above site.
Eclipse is a self contained program, all the files you need are in the Eclipse folder, wherever you downloaded it to.